# GraphQL / Typescript / Serverless error - "Unable to find any GraphQL type definitions for the following pointers"

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, serverless, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy my GraphQL API with serverless framework and I'm getting the following error when deploying. Bear in mind this works fine locally:

```
Unable to find any GraphQL type definitions for the following pointers
```

I have noticed that the graphql.schema file is not in the .build folder, and still isn't there after adding:

```yaml
    package:
      include:
        - graphql/schema.graphql
```

to my serverless.yml.

Here is my server.js:

```js
/* eslint-disable import/prefer-default-export */
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startServerAndCreateLambdaHandler, handlers } from '@as-integrations/aws-lambda';
import { addResolversToSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import resolvers from './resolvers';

const { loadSchemaSync } = require('@graphql-tools/load');
const { GraphQLFileLoader } = require('@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader');

const schema = loadSchemaSync('./**/*.graphql', {
  loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()],
});

const schemaWithResolvers = addResolversToSchema({
  schema,
  resolvers,
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: schemaWithResolvers,
});

export const graphqlHandler = startServerAndCreateLambdaHandler(
  server,
  handlers.createAPIGatewayProxyEventV2RequestHandler(),
);
```

schema.graphql:

```
type Query {
  hello: String,
  getCopyCat(input: String!): String
}
```

Serverless.yml:

```yaml
service: undecided

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-2

functions:
  graphql:
    handler: graphql/server.graphqlHandler 
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: POST
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: GET
    package:
      include:
        - graphql/schema.graphql

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
```

Comment: did you figure this out?